# Populating combobox using data from an API

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

The idea of this program is to retrieve the employee user ID (or signature) from an API URL once the name has been entered.

Right now my program shows no errors, however when I press start, my combo box (labeled "Name") doesn't show any suggestion as it is intended to. I would like it suggest name when the user is typing names (similar to how google works).

I have tried the `ComboBox.DisplayMember, ComboBox.ValueMember, and ComboBox.DataSource`, However, my data source is taken from an API JSON.

Thank you for your help in advance.

This is my JSON string:

```
[{
        "signature": "JANDOW",
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "fullName": "Dow, Jane",
        "lastName": "Dow"
    }
]
```

My forms code is

```
    namespace TimeSheets_Try_11
    
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            WebAPI WA = new WebAPI();
          
    
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlIora);
            }
    
            private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
   
    
                string sgname; string projectstring;
                projectstring = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
                sgname = WA.Getsignature(projectstring);
                textBox2.Text = sgname;
    
    
            }
    
            private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                
            }
    
            private void button1_Click(AutoCompleteStringCollection combData)
            {
                
                
            }
        
            private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                
            }
        }

}
```

Code for calling out the JSON is:

```
namespace TimeSheets_Try_11.Controllers
{
    class WebAPI
    {
        public string Getsignature(string name)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlIora), false);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            wc.Headers.Add("Cookie:" + cookies);
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            string uri = "";

            uri = StaticStrings.UrlIora + name;
            var response = wc.DownloadString(uri);

            var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employeename>>(response);

            string signame = status.Select(js => js.signature).First();
            return signame;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for defining variables is:

```
namespace TimeSheet_Try11_Models
{

        
        public class Employeename
        {
            public string signature { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string fullName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public List<Employeename> Employeename { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

[image: Windows Forms design]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the JSON is an array. You need to change your method to accommodate for that:

```
        public List<string> Getsignature(string name)
        {
            ...

            var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employeename>>(response);

            return status.Select(emp => emp.signature).ToList();
        }
```

Then you need to bind up your ComboBox correctly:

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {    
                comboBox1.DataSource = WA.Getsignature(textBox2.Text);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I am now getting an error saying: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'"